# ¿Cómo hacer para que se muestre un popup al seleccionar una opción?

Tags: javascript, html

Como dice el titulo, quiero que al seleccionar un determinado "radio", cuando le de click a un boton, este muestre un popup y redireccione a otra pagina.

Mi código:

```js
///funcion para mostrar el popup
function mostrarDatos() {
    var valor1 = $("input[id='A']:checked").val();
    var valor2 = $("input[id='B']:checked").val();
    var valor3 = $("input[id='C']:checked").val();
    
    if(valor1 === "True"){
        alert("Selecciona un metodo de pago.");
    }
}

/// funcion para cerrar el cuadro del popup
    function SaveAndHide1(star) {
        palet1.style.display = "none";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="palet1" style="display:none;">
    <h2 style="line-height: 2px;">Envíos de palets</h2>
    <p>Si el PALET a enviar no es apilable, existe un cargo adicional que pude variar en un rango de 200 a 500 EUROS. Se recomienda enviar una foto del PALET que se está enviando una vez se realice la compra del servicio indicado el IDENTIFICADOR de compra.</p>
    <div class="close _close" id="close">
        <a href=javascript:; class="btn_close_nuevo btn" onclick="SaveAndHide1(this)">Aceptar</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" id="A" value="P"> <b>Europeo</b> &nbsp
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" id="B" value="P"><b>Americano</b> &nbsp
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" id="C" value="P"><b>Otros</b>

<a href="/pagina" id="enviar_add_evento" class="boton_registrar" onClick="mostrarDatos()" tabindex="13">BUSCAR</a>
```

Estaba intentando hacer funciones basicas pero no me funciona.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende y tu HTML es incorrecto. No puede haber dos o más elementos con el mismo `id`. Además tienes radios con un contenido idéntico en todo, ¿por qué? Se nota que hay confusión en la lógica que estás implementando. Si explicas mejor lo que quieres lograr te podremos ayudar a resolver el problema en base a un contenido correcto. Saludos.

Comment: Ademas los botones deberian tener diferentes valores.

Comment: Ya esta, lo edite, lo siento, un lapsus.
La idea es que al momento de seleccionar una opcion del radio, en este caso la de Europeo, muestre un popup, que es "palet1", pero que se muestra al clickear sobre el boton "buscar" y luego redireccione a X pagina web

Comment: hola **Eduardo Leon** puedes ser mas especifico en tu pregunta, que quieres que haga el poppup que mensaje mostrara, mostrara el mensaje y luego se diseccionara?. para poder ayudarte pronto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

cambia tu boton asi

BUSCAR

con el siguien jquery detectas el valor selecionado al apretar el boton o link en tu caso

```js
$('#enviar_add_evento').on('click', function() {
   alert($('input[name=tipo]:checked').val()); 
});
```

ahora resta levantar el popup, ahora no se cual la nesesidad de levantar el popup dado que con solo apretar el boton puedes redirigir, algo como esto te redireciona

window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

lo otro te recomiendo que value de los input cambie para poder identificarlos mejor y con ese valor determinar a donde redirigir

ejemplo

**Europeo** &nbsp
**Americano** &nbsp
**Otros**

Answer (score 0):

Segun he entendido, necesitas que al hacer clic en buscar te muestre un `alert` diferente segund lo seleccionado y luego te redirija.
Lo que necesitas es los `inputs` con el mismo `name` pero con `values` diferentes que sera lo que se mostrara dependiendo de la eleccion que hagas.

> Es remendado tener un de los valores seleccionado por defecto para no mandar valor en blanco, utilizando el atributo `checked`

```
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" value="europeo" checked> <b>Europeo</b> 
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" value="americano"><b>Americano</b> 
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" class="tipo-envio" value="otros"><b>Otros</b>
```

Despues de ello en la funcion `mostrarDatos()`:

```
function mostrarDatos() {
    // Seleccionas el el valor del radio que esta seleccionado en dicho momento
    var seleccionado = $(".tipo-envio").val();

    //Muestras la opcion que se ha seleccionado
    alert("Se ha seleccionado la opcion: "+seleccionado);

    //Esto se ejecutara cuando el popup de alert se cierre:
    //Redirije a donde necesites
    window.location.href = "https://es.stackoverflow.com";

}
```